# Removing Punctuation from a set of results

Tags: sql-server-2014, trim

I have a query as below

```
select ContactName,Address, concat(City,' ', StateOrRegion,' ',PostalCode) as 'Region Info'
from Customers
```

with the results here

```
Maria Anders    Obere Str. 57                     Berlin  12209
Ana Trujillo    Avda. de la Constitución 2222   México D.F.  05021
Antonio Moreno  Mataderos  2312                  México D.F.  05023
Thomas Hardy    120 Hanover Sq.                   London  WA1 1DP
Christina Berglund    Berguvsvägen  8                  Luleå  S-958 22            
Hanna Moos       Forsterstr. 57                     Mannheim  68306
Frédérique Citeaux  24, place Kléber           Strasbourg  67000
Martín Sommer   C/ Araquil, 67                 Madrid  28023
Laurence Lebihan    12, rue des Bouchers      Marseille  13008
Elizabeth Lincoln   23 Tsawassen Blvd.     Tsawassen BC T2F 8M4
```

My question is in the address field can I remove the punctuation without creating a table and if so what is the best way to go about it.  would working with Ltrim and or rtrim be a possibility to this?

Comment: Yes, you can easily get rid of characters like periods and commas. Yes, you can use trim functions to get rid of that extra whitespace. But what do you want, why do you want it in a single column that way? Addresses get pretty messy and you've got international locations up there.

Comment: @shawnt00 Good question about "why is this being done". I am not sure that the O.P. asking about LTRIM/RTRIM is regarding spaces. In C#, at least, Trim, TrimStart, and [TrimEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) can remove more than spaces if you asking them to.

Comment: Yeah, that's part of my confusion. Trimming refers to the ends of the strings. But the punctuation characters can appear internally as well.

Comment: @shawnt00 I have no real idea here as it can be a simple mis-use of terminology ;-). I was just saying that it _could_ be what the O.P. was referring to since a few of the address lines do end with a period. But I agree, the wording of the question is ambiguous and unclear, and it would help improve the accuracy of the proposed answers for it to be clarified.

Comment: @srutzky I think good software types have to be tuned to misuses of words from all kinds of people and I fully agree.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a limited set of items you want to remove, you can simply use `REPLACE(x, y, z)` to replace the characters you want to remove with a zero-length string.  `x` is the string to be searched, `y` is the string to find, and `z` is the string to replace `y` with.

An example:

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(50);
SET @a = 'This, is a test.';
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@a, '.', ''), ',', '');
```

This will remove both the comma and the period from the string.  Depending on the scale of your problem, this may work well.

Instead of using `CONCAT()`, why not simply use `+` to concatenate the values?

I'd rewrite your query as:

```
SELECT c.ContactName
    , c.Address
    , [Region Info] = c.City + ' ' + c.StateOrRegion + ' ' + c.PostalCode
FROM dbo.Customers c;
```

You may notice I've capitalized the keywords in my query; this provides a great way to easily recognize keywords separately from column and table names, etc.

Also, you want to explicitly specify the schema; normally this is `dbo`.  This will make your code less susceptible to problems in future if someone creates a new schema that happens to contain a table with the same name as the ones in your `FROM` clause.

You should also get in the habit of specifying an alias for items in the `FROM` clause, and use that alias in the other parts of your query.  This makes debugging a lot simpler down the road.